# IRC BOT (python)

Tags: python, sockets, irc

```
sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sck.connect((irc, port))
sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + 'NICKSERV' + 'ghost' + 'supaBOT' + 'htown')
sck.send('NICK supaBOT\r\n')
sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + 'NICKSERV' + 'IDENTIFY' + 'password')
sck.send('USER supaBOT supaBOT supaBOT :supaBOT Script\r\n')
sck.send('JOIN ' + " " + chan + '\r\n')
```

when I try running the script I get this error:

```
trix.gonullyourself.org 451 PRIVMSG  You have not registered
trix.gonullyourself.org 451 PRIVMSG  You have not registered
trix.gonullyourself.org 451 JOIN  You have not registered
: You
```

The nick supaBOT is registered on the server, but I dont know how to identify to the server, since the code above is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Mike said, you're not sending the data you should be sending. You need to add the spaces there and you need `:` before final command arguments if they have spaces. Some of the lines are also missing `'\r\n'`.

That is, the format for a `PRIVMSG` is: `'PRIVMSG nick :message with spaces\r\n'`

`PRIVMSG` only has two arguments, so you need to put the `:` there to indicate that the rest of the line is only one value which may include spaces.

The reason you are getting `"You have not registered"` is because you must send `USER` and `NICK` commands before any other commands. And if the `NICK` command fails (nick collision), you must detect the error and try another one. Once you have sent a valid `USER` and `NICK` commands, some IRC networks also send you a `PING`, to which you must respond with a `PONG` before the server considers you "registered". After that you may use other commands.

Comment: That works, I dont get any errors, but the bot is not identifying to nickserv for some strange reason :|

Comment: @SourD Are you using `'PRIVMSG NICKSERV :IDENTIFY password\r\n'`? Does it respond with anything? What irc network are you using?

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I already fixed this problem, using `'PRIVMSG NICKSERV IDENTIFY password\r\n'` without the `:`

Comment: @SourD If that works, the irc server does not conform to the irc protocol specification. The specification disallows spaces inside parameters unless it's the last parameter and it is prefixed with `:`. See the sections on [message format](http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/chapter2.html#c2_3) and [private messages](http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/chapter4.html#c4_4_1).

Answer (score 0):

check your strings, `'PRIVMSG ' + 'NICKSERV' + 'IDENTIFY' + 'password'`  prints `PRIVMSG NICKSERVIDENTIFYpassword` which is obviously not what you're want to send

Ftr, it's best to use string substitution or .format() because concocting them, that adds extra overhead as each letter forces python to cycle through the string, before it adds the letter.  i.e. :`'PRIVMSG NICKSERV IDENTIFY %s' %(password)` or `'PRIVMSG NICKSERV IDENTIFY {0}'.format(password)`

also there is an irclib existing already if you want to use that (and supybot exists/existed and is a pure python irc bot).